# Proving $\sin(\theta)-\sin[(n+1)\theta] + \sin(n\theta)=4\sin(\frac{\theta}2)\sin(\frac{n+1}2\theta)\sin(\frac{n}2\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove, using only real trigonometric identities, the following indentity:

$$\sin(\theta)-\sin[(n+1)\theta] + \sin(n\theta)=4\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\theta\right)\sin\left(\frac{n}{2}\theta\right)$$

Not even sure of how to start.

Comment: Google "Sum-to-Product" Identity

Comment: Could you show me how you do it? Maybe I'm blind, but I don't find very useful those formule

Comment: $\sin(x) + \sin(y) = 2\sin(\frac{x+y}{2})\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})$. The x and y can be any expression.

Comment: $\sin(x)+\sin(y)+\sin(z)=?$

Comment: $(\sin(x)+\sin(y))+\sin(z)$ ...

Comment: But then you don't have a sum of sines, you would have $2\sin(\frac{x+y}{2})\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})+\sin(z)$

Comment: Are you sure there is *no* sum of sines?

Comment: I can't see such sum

Comment: @Numox: Work through what $2\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\cos\frac{x-y}{2}$ yields when $x$ and $y$ are appropriate expressions from your target identity. Then see if you can write the remaining $\sin z$ in a way that helps it combine with that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sin \theta - \sin (n+1)\theta  + \sin n\theta & =\sin \theta - (\sin n\theta \cos \theta + \cos n\theta \sin \theta ) + \sin n\theta \\
 & = \sin \theta(1 - \cos n\theta) +  \sin n\theta (1 - \cos \theta) \\
 & = 2 \sin \theta \sin^2 \frac{n\theta}{2} + 2 \sin n\theta  \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} \\
&  = 4 \sin \frac\theta2 \cos \frac\theta2 \sin^2 \frac{n\theta}{2} + 4 \sin \frac{n\theta}2 \cos \frac{n\theta}2  \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}\\ 
 & = 4 \sin \frac\theta2 \sin \frac{n\theta}{2} \left( \cos \frac\theta2 \sin \frac{n\theta}{2} + \cos \frac{n\theta}2  \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \right) \\
& = 4 \sin \frac\theta2 \sin \frac{n\theta}{2} \sin \frac{(n+1)\theta}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much!